# Switch between emulator and device in Mono for Android

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am using Mono for Android with MonoDevelop on a Mac. I'm interested in being able to debug on the emulator at one point and then switch to the device. What I found was that the first time I try to debug I am prompted with a dialog to choose the emulator or the device. As soon as I choose one MD remembers it and I can't switch.

How do I choose where to deploy for debugging purposes?

Comment: You can always right click your Android project and deploy to any devices from `Run With`.

Comment: Yeah, but the debugger doesn't attach

Comment: You may try click Project(on the top menu)->Android Device Target to set target device.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! Feel free to answer the question so I can mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `Project`(on the top menu), then `Android Device Target` to set debugging device.